# Why are files named "types.go" are ignored in goland?

Tags: go, goland

Since a few days, Goland is not recognizing files named "types.go" as go source files. This is just a problem for syntax highlighting, as the project still runs normally, but it's quite annoying, because it affects both files from my project and from the standard library.

Whenever I try to import the ignored file I get the error:

```
Build constraints exclude all the Go files in '/[REDACTED]/internal/api/types'
```

But the file just contains some types definitions, without any build constraint directive.

For example here is a file called types.go

[image: Here is an example of the types.go file]

And here the same file renamed

[image]

I already tried to invalidate caches, reinstall go and Goland but the problem still remains

Comment: Does the import work once you've renamed the file?

Comment: @mkopriva yes, as you can see in my second example the red squiggly line disappears from the "api" package, because the imports are fixed

Comment: And have you tried building the project outside of GoLand? E.g. `go build`? Does *that* work, or do you get the same error?

Comment: @mkopriva yes, the project runs fine, both inside and outside Goland...this is just a problem for syntax highlight

Comment: @GiulioGialanella getting an error like *"Build constraints exclude all the Go files in ..."* when trying to import a package is hardly *"just a problem for syntax highlight"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`types.go` is recognized as a plain-text file for some reason. You can navigate to *Preferences/Settings | Editor | File Types* find *File type auto-detected by content* or *Text* and exclude `types.go` from the patterns list.

[image]

Feel free to follow [IDEA-258255](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-258255) to make the process clearer.

Comment: You saved my day for a related problem, in my case the file constants.go was in the "file type auto-detected by file content" section, but it wasn't recognized as a go file.